# Where is `__FLT_MAX__` constant defined on Ubuntu?

Tags: gcc

I am learning C programming using `gcc` compiler under Ubuntu 14.04 (64bits).
As a practice, I am trying to locate the definitions of size limits of multiple C data types.

I have easily located `limits.h` in `/usr/include`, and found the explicit definitions of constants such as

```
#  define INT_MAX   2147483647
```

in it.

I Also found out that `float.h` is located in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include`. However, I didn't find the explicit defintion of, say, `FLT_MAX`. What I got is

```
#define FLT_MAX     __FLT_MAX__
```

But where is the definition of `__FLT_MAX__`? Or where does the C preprocessor get the value of it?

**Reference**:
 Here is a [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1545401) on [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/) which also asked the same question (but didn't get solved).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`__FLT_MAX__` is a [pre-defined macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Predefined-Macros.html#Predefined-Macros). You'll probably have to look inside the GCC source to see *where* it is defined, but it's easy to what it is defined to:

> The C preprocessor normally predefines several macros that indicate
>   what type of system and machine is in use. They are obviously
>   different on each target supported by GCC. This manual, being for all
>   systems and machines, cannot tell you what their names are, but you
>   can use cpp -dM to see them all.

So:

```
$ cpp -dM <<<'' | grep 'FLT_MAX'
#define __FLT_MAX_10_EXP__ 38
#define __FLT_MAX_EXP__ 128
#define __FLT_MAX__ 3.40282346638528859812e+38F
```